# I want to display a custom image behind my table view in my iPhone App

Tags: xcode, background, uitableview

Xcode comes up with a error and states that I need have a UITableViewControler instance to control my table view but im not sure how to do this.

I have searched through all of the university of Google and cant find something that tells me how to do this.

Please help, very new to Xcode.

Comment: You want to set the Image on your UITableView Background ??

Answer (score 0):

I started working with xcode after going through a "class". Look for Standford University CS 193P in iTunesU and you will find a very well structured and explained course.
Here is their website:
http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/downloads-2011-fall
What you are looking for is in lecture 9, but I recommend going through all of the lectures as they strongly connected.